# Expand a visual selection in the other direction

Tags: visual-mode

Sometimes I have selected a visual selection with, for example, `Vjjjjj`, only to realize later that I should have started the selection one line higher. However, pressing `k` simply decreases the lower range of the selection rather than moving the entire selection up one line.

Here's a *visual*ization (ha, ha), where the bolded lines are the ones I have selected:

```
Do not select this line
Do not select this line
Select this line!        
Select this line!        <-- I pressed V here...
Select this line!
Select this line!
Select this line!
Select this line!        <-- ... and moved to here. But I should have started my
Do not select this line      selection one line higher!
Do not select this line
```

How can I extend a visual selection by moving its starting point in the other direction? If this is not possible, is there any way to add a mapping in my .vimrc that enables me to do so?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the `o` command, from `:help v_o`:

> Go to Other end of highlighted text: The current         cursor
>   position becomes the start of the highlighted     text and the cursor
>   is moved to the other end of the     highlighted text.  The
>   highlighted area remains the      same.

So when you have finished selecting the lines you want press <kbd>o</kbd>, the cursor will move to the beginning of the selection and you can select the line before by pressing <kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: JAW DROPPED when i pressed `o`, :O